# Unexpected session logout when opening settings

Tags: login, xorg

Every time I open settings (from the right corner menu or by searching it with SUPER), a black screen appears and then the login is displayed.

After re-login the whole session is lost.

Here is the Xorg log (`/home/myUserName/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log.old`):

```
[   463.962] (EE) Backtrace:
[   463.962] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13c) [0x555b6a607eec]
[   463.963] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x60) [0x7f83bb277420]
[   463.964] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f83bb0b200b]
[   463.965] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0x12b) [0x7f83bb091859]
[   463.966] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[   463.966] (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (?+0x0) [0x7f83bb091729]
[   463.967] (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__assert_fail+0x46) [0x7f83bb0a2fd6]
[   463.968] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRIMoveBuffersHelper+0xc15) [0x555b6a5d23a5]
[   463.968] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2Authenticate+0xa2) [0x555b6a5d45e2]
[   463.968] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2GetParam+0x944) [0x555b6a5d5614]
[   463.969] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x354) [0x555b6a4a5fd4]
[   463.969] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3b4) [0x555b6a4aa084]
[   463.970] (EE) 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f83bb093083]
[   463.970] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2e) [0x555b6a493ace]
[   463.970] (EE) 
[   463.970] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   463.970] (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
[   463.970] (EE) 
[   463.970] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   463.970] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/myUserName/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   463.970] (EE) 
[   463.997] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

May help know that before the last shutdown I used Bluetooth to pair it with headphones, so something may goes wrong with that.

All worked fine till yesterday and I didn't update anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same stacktrace on LMDE 6, whenever I tried to open Cheese and some other app. Fixed for myself by installing xserver-xorg-video-nvidia (instead of preinstalled xserver-xorg-video-nouveau).

disclaimer: obviously, this would only apply to you, if you have an nvidia GPU, and don't have problems running the proprietary driver. If you run an AMD GPU, or have a built-in GPU only, then you **must not** install the nvidia driver.